# I deployed my Django server via Heroku, the build was successful, but keep getting 'Application Error' on the deployed URL

Tags: python, django, heroku

I deployed my Django server via Heroku, the build was successful.  Whenever I go to the deployed URL, I get an application error without no specific error.  It just says for me to check my logs.  Here is my log. Is there something Im missing? still new to deploying with Heroku.

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
-----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/environ/environ.py:630: UserWarning: /tmp/build_b0b32caa_/portfolio_project/.env doesn't exist - if you're not configuring your environment separately, create one.
         "environment separately, create one." % env_file)
       330 static files copied to '/tmp/build_b0b32caa_/staticfiles'.
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 71M
-----> Launching...
       Released v19
       https://coreys-portfolio-server.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: That's your _deploy_ log. We need to see your _runtime logs_. Run `heroku logs` and see what that gives you.

Answer (score -1):

If you app runs fine on your own computer then you can try restarting your app with `heroku restart`

Comment: ...what makes you think this will help? The question doesn't give us any information whatsoever, and it is very rare that restarting dynos manually makes sense.